# Oracle How can I keep two tables in sync using a trigger that gets activated based on a timestamp field?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to do a one-time import/export to copy data from TableA to TableB. However, after the one-time import of data, I will need to keep the tables in sync using a trigger until we are ready to use the new table.

Is it possible to write a trigger which copies data from one table to another depending upon the value of a timestamp field in tableA OR use a condition on systimestamp. The trigger on the attribute is preferred, but if that is not possible, then I can go for systimestamp?

I am a newbie to Oracle and I will be very grateful if someone could help me come up with such a trigger.

```
TableA
CREATE TABLE user.tableA (
    attr1 ... NOT NULL,
    attr2 ...,
    ...,
    attrN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT tableA_PK PRIMARY KEY (attr1) ENABLE
 )

user.tableB is the same as user.tableA
```

Need to come up with a trigger to copy inserts from TableA to TableB.
The code below needs work

```
CREATE TRIGGER user.sync_from_A_to_B
  AFTER INSERT ON user.tableA
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if (systimestamp OR attrN >= to_timestamp('2021-07-31 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  then
    INSERT INTO user.tableB
         (
             attr1,
             attr2,
             ...,
             attrN
         )
         VALUES
         (
             :new.attr1,
             :new.attr1,
             :new....,
             :new.attrN
         )
  end if;
END;
/
```

Comment: Why would you need to check a timestamp? An INSERT trigger will only fire for a row that is _currently being inserted_. It's a new row, so just copy it to tableB. An alternative solution would be to just make tableB a materialized view of tableA.

Comment: Materialized view should do exactly what you need

Comment: What's going to be different about the new table? You can probably use dbms_redefinition for migrating from one table structure to another - this allows you to map columns together and have Oracle guarantee syncing the table up before swapping the new table in for the old table. Materialized views are for if you want to keep both tables, it doesn't sound like that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Convenient way to sync two table with native features is to create [materialized view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B) with fast refresh on commit. Essentially it is a table and query definition to fill that table. Oracle then updates target table when refresh occurs (`on commit` in your case). Then you may drop materialized view and keep the table (so remove the query definition and any dependency on a base table) to rebase your application to it.

```
SQL> set echo on
SQL> 
SQL> create table t_a (
  2    id primary key,
  3    val,
  4    str
  5  ) as
  6  select level, level, chr(32 + level)
  7  from dual
  8  connect by level < 4;

Table T_A created.
 
SQL> select * from t_a;

        ID        VAL STR 
---------- ---------- ----
         1          1 !   
         2          2 "   
         3          3 #   
 
SQL> create materialized view log on t_a
  2  with primary key /*To enable incremental updates*/;

Materialized view log T_A created.

SQL> create materialized view t_b
  2  refresh on commit fast
  3  as
  4  select * from t_a;

Materialized view T_B created.

SQL> select * from t_b;

        ID        VAL STR 
---------- ---------- ----
         1          1 !   
         2          2 "   
         3          3 #   

SQL> insert into t_a values(10, 11, 'W');

1 row inserted.

SQL> update t_a set val = 100 where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from t_b;

        ID        VAL STR 
---------- ---------- ----
         1          1 !   
         2          2 "   
         3          3 #   

SQL> /*Still no changes*/ 
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
 
SQL> select * from t_b;

        ID        VAL STR 
---------- ---------- ----
         2          2 "   
         3          3 #   
         1        100 !   
        10         11 W   
 
SQL> /*Looks ok, we're moving to target table*/
SQL> drop materialized view t_b preserve table;

Materialized view T_B dropped.
 
SQL> drop table t_a;

Table T_A dropped.
 
SQL> select * from t_b;

        ID        VAL STR 
---------- ---------- ----
         2          2 "   
         3          3 #   
         1        100 !   
        10         11 W
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that a materialized view will not satisfy your need. True, it is much better than trigger enforced synchronization but the crux of the question seems to be *until we are ready to use the new table*.
This implies at some future time in the source table (tableA) will be discontinued (dropped?). If so then at that time the materialized view refresh becomes invalid.  
You, however, do not need an after row trigger, but an after statement trigger. That trigger would insert directly from TableA to TableB.

```
create trigger user.sync_from_a_to_b
  after insert on user.tablea 
begin
    insert into user.tableb
         (
             attr1,
             attr2,
             ...,
             attrn
         )
      select 
             attr1,
             attr2,
             ...,
             attrn
       from tablea 
      where attrn >= (select max attrn from tableb);  
end;
```

The primary issue you face is synchronization will require processing Delete and Updates as well. Perhaps your best bet in a two phase approach. Create a
materialized view until your ready to cut over to your new table. Then do your *one time* cutover directly from the MV to your new table.

Comment: Nice. I do not know much about materialized views and don't have much time to explore it. However, I was looking at the syntax of a trigger. There is a WHEN clause on the trigger. Is it possible to use that WHEN clause to achieve the above?

Comment: FYI: There are no deletes and updates on my TableA

Comment: NO! at lease using STATEMENT level triggers where the WHEN clause is not  valid. You could use it with a ROW level trigger and a hard coded value (as in your initial query). I have never tried but I would doubt WHEN can have a select (you could write a test cast).  But this would have much lower performance, if you do any thing other that 1 row at a time.  If you inserted 1000 rows then your trigger must run 1000 times.  Let me suggest you do not have the time to NOT INVESTIGATE MVs..  You are an Oracle newbie, so here is a suggestion: ASK an experienced developer or DBA.

Comment: Now I understand the difference between the statement and row-level trigger. However, TableA has row-level inserts only. So it will be the same for statement level as well as row-level inserts. I will ask the DBA if he has any experience with materialized views.

If I add a clause like WHEN new.attrN >= to_timestamp('2021-07-19 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), will it make the trigger very slow?